# EZDecompressionError using TStreamReader with TZDecompressionStream

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I have a program that works fine in XE2 but now fails in XE6.  Tracing the problem isn't too difficult.  I create a TZDecompressionStream using the built in zip handling classes and submit this to a TStreamReader.  The code is intended to support plain uncompressed files and compressed files and hence the reader is pointed at a "FileStream" variable that is either a TFileStream (which works) or a TZDecompressionStream (which exhibits the fault)

```
Reader := TStreamReader.Create(FileStream, TEncoding.ASCII);
```

The problem is that TStreamReader, when it reads data, calls an internal routine AdjustEndOfBuffer that attempts to make sure that the buffer always contains only complete characters.  Unfortunately this has the following line which rewinds the stream if necessary but is invoked whther there is a need for a rewind or not

```
FStream.Position := FStream.Position - Rewind;
```

where in my case Rewind has a value of zero and the TZDecompressionStream takes exception to this.  Obviously this is a fault in TZDecompressionStream in that a seek to the current position should be evaluated as OK since it is a no-op.  The actual Seek is expressed in TStreamReader as move to current offset relative to the beginning of the stream.

The actual code in TZDecompressionStream.Seek allows a return to start (ie rewind the stream), move forward past the current position and move to end but specifically does not allow a move which would give exactly the current position.  The following code adjudicates permission to move forward

```
(((NativeUInt(offset) - FZStream.total_out) > 0) and (Origin = soBeginning))
```

but should have a >= as below

```
(((NativeUInt(offset) - FZStream.total_out) >= 0) and (Origin = soBeginning))
```

Does anyone know a way around this fault without simply abandoning the TStreamReader?  Is there a way to modify the behaviour of the TZDecompressionStream which has been created for my by the TzipFile class?

Comment: It's far from clear to me what you are doing. I don't understand where text encoding comes into a decompression code. Perhaps if there was an mcve it would be clear.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: `TStreamReader` reads bytes from an underlying `TStream` and converts them to text using the specified `TEncoding`. The input file in question is compressed, thus the use of `TZDecompressionStream` as the `TStream` so the bytes are decompressed before then converted to text.

Comment: @Remy That makes sense if FileStream is a decompression stream

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: "*I create a TZDecompressionStream ... and submit this to a TStreamReader*", I think that implies that `FileStream` is a `TZDecompressionStream`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've tried to clarify the position.  The issue is that I have diagnosed the fault in the Delphi Zip library but I'm not sure of the best way (if any) to work around it.  Really I want to use a descendant class of TZDecompressionStream with a slightly modified Seek but since I don't create the object I'm not sure how to manage this.

Comment: I'm with you now. Sorry. You could simply change the code. Add the modified unit to your project. And then it should work. BTW, this is zlib rather than zip I think.

Comment: Or you could wrap this stream in another stream that forwards all methods to the underlying stream, apart from null seeks. That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with my own answer which avoids messing with the VCL source code.  This isn't a very nice thing to do but it is fairly brief and avoids any confusion for other parts of the system.  I've implemented a class TsptZDecompressionStream that overrides the faulty Seek and essentially no-ops the move by zero.  I have a class function Convert that replaces the VMT pointer in a TZDecompressionStream with the VMT pointer for my new class.  This should be safe as the classes are identical in all respects except for the overridden method.  Anyone else experiencing the same problem should be able to simply use this code and call

```
TsptZDecompressionStream.Convert(Stream as TZDecompressionStream);
```

to trigger the conversion

Declaration

```
type
  TsptZDecompressionStream = class(TZDecompressionStream)
    class procedure Convert(DecompressionStream: TZDecompressionStream);
    function Seek(const Offset: Int64; Origin: TSeekOrigin): Int64; override;
  end;
```

implementation

```
{ TsptZDecompressionStream }

class procedure TsptZDecompressionStream.Convert(DecompressionStream: TZDecompressionStream);
begin
  // switch vmt pointer to point to TsptZDecompressionStream vmt
  PPointer(DecompressionStream)^ := PPointer(TsptZDecompressionStream);
end;

function TsptZDecompressionStream.Seek(const Offset: Int64; Origin: TSeekOrigin): Int64;
begin
  if (Origin = soBeginning) and (Offset = Position) then
  begin
    Result := Offset;
    Exit;
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := inherited Seek(Offset, Origin);
  end;
end;
```

I can't think of any reason why this is a particularly bad idea other than the usual issue of hacking the internal data formats but I would welcome further comments.

Note that the implementation is for the 64bit Seek as this is the version implemented by TZDecompressionStream.  Delphi now directs that all streams should implement either the 32bit version (old seek method signature) or the 64bit version.  Bear in mind that my code will not function in conjunction with any version of TZDecompressionStream that implements the 32bit Seek (I don't know if it dates back far enough for this to have ever been the case)

Comment: This seems way more complex than you need. Why mess with VMT? Why not instantiate the derived class? In essence doing what I suggested in my final comment.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  The way the RTL zlib wrapper works means you have no control over the class type of the stream.  The Read method has an out parameter to return the stream object generated inside the library.  I could wrap this stream but it means hooking up lots of methods which is rather a lot of boiler-plate code.  I agree that hacking the VMT is a rather uncomfortable step but it is at least concise.

Comment: OK. I see. In that case I think I would replace zlib.pas with a modified version. That would be my personal choice, but I agree that this does come down to personal preferences. I currently have to replace zlib.pas anyway to fix the performance of zlib under x64, so I'm comfortable with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more elegant? solution is to use so called interceptor classes, essentially classes with the same name as the original, that are derived from the original. I have frequently used these to great effect.

The method is described in a few places on the net, for example here

[interceptor classes](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2009/qt/interceptor.htm)

You have to be a bit careful with the order of uses clauses but beyond that they work fine.

the coding is almost exactly as per your example, except for the naming and the fact that conversion is no longer necessary.

```
type
  TZDecompressionStream= class(TZDecompressionStream)
    function Seek(const Offset: Int64; Origin: TSeekOrigin): Int64; override;
  end;
```

Comment: In a comment to his answer, the asker explains that the framework instantiates the class. Thus subclassing won't work.